# sed extract with multiple options in end pattern

Tags: sed

I get some output from a command, I have to extract text between two patterns from the output. Start pattern is fixed. But the end format can be one of two (lets say word2-1 and word2-2).

Is there any way I can specify that in a single `sed` command?

I tried

```
sed -n "/Word1/,/(word2-1|word2-2)/p"
sed -n "/Word1/,/word2-1|word2-2/p"
sed -n "/Word1/,/word2-1\|word2-2/p"
sed -n "/Word1/,/[word2-1|word2-2]/p"
```

Comment: The third one is correct. Show us the sample input for which not works.

Comment: ok. I missed a point. Sorry for that.

Output can have both the end patterns, but cmd should extract till the first occurrence (does not matter which second word comes first).

Answer (score 1):

The regexp that matches `word2-1` and `word2-2` and nothing else is `word2-[12]`. If the suffix has more than one character, use `word2-\(first\|second\)` or whatever.

Your third regexp matches the same strings, just with more repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Your third option works, only extracting to the first match as you stated in your comment:

```
$ cat > file << 'EOF'
> foo
> bar
> Word1
> foo
> bar
> word2-2
> foo
> bar
> word2-1
> EOF
$ sed -n "/Word1/,/word2-1\|word2-2/p" file
Word1
foo
bar
word2-2
```

Comment: What if file has word2-1 before word2-2 and I want to extract 
(word2-1/wor2-2 whichever comes first).

Comment: @Ram That is the way that `sed` operates already.

Comment: I am in FreeBSD and the following works fine.
sed -n -E "/Word1/,/Word2-1/p" | sed -n -E "/Word1/,/Word2-2/p"
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ram Capitalisation is important.

Comment: @Ram, it might work fine, but also twice.